# Why does HostnameVerifier return false in this case?

Tags: java, ssl, https

I'm trying to understand how the `HostnameVerifier` works. Can you explain why this returns false?

```java
public static void main(String[] argv) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    String host = "stackoverflow.com";
    Integer port = 443;
    SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(host, port);

    if (socket.isConnected()) {
        boolean valid = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier().verify(host, socket.getSession());
        System.out.println("valid is " + valid);
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: That hostname verifier is *only* used when the standard hostname verification logic fails. So the default is to always return false. If you have some custom hostname verification logic to use when the standard hostname verification logic fails, you can put that in your own home-made HostnameVerifier. See [JSSE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/security/java-security-overview1.html#GUID-2EF91196-D468-4D0F-8FDC-DA2BEA165D10).

Comment: The docs for [setHostnameVerifier](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html#setDefaultHostnameVerifier(javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier) seems to explain it.

Comment: NB `socket.isConnected()` cannot possibly be false at the point you are testing it. An exception would have been thrown if the connect failed. Don't write pointless code.